# get event when user has selected a text in any window in X11

Tags: x11, programming, events

I want to write an app that shows a popup-menu after a user has selected a text in any window in Linux (debian based).
Mac users may know "PopClip" (https://pilotmoon.com/popclip/) and as I was not able to find anything comparable on Linux,
I started writing it on my own for Linux.

But I am quite new to programming in X11 and I am wondering how to be notified in a c programm,
when the user has selected a text in any window?

I found several examples to be notified on e.g. mouse events like

```
    window = DefaultRootWindow(display);
    XMapWindow(display, window); 
    
    XAllowEvents(display, AsyncBoth, CurrentTime);
    
    XGrabPointer(display, window, True, 
        PointerMotionMask | ButtonPressMask | ButtonReleaseMask , GrabModeAsync, GrabModeAsync, None, None, CurrentTime);

    while(1) {
        XNextEvent(display, &xevent);        
        switch (xevent.type) {
        ...
```

and I also found that one can be notified on `SelectionNotify` but that really does not do what I am looking for.

Any examples known?

Comment: Can you clarify what’s lacking with `SelectionNotify`? See [`xclipd`](https://github.com/jhunt/xclipd/blob/master/src/xclipd.c), it illustrates how to find out about selection changes.

Comment: @StephenKitt, simply because I do not want to put the text in the clipboard and I do not want to interfere with the clipboard itself. But thanks anyway, I will have a look to xclipd

Comment: There isn’t really a clipboard in X11, just a notion of clipboard ownership; see [this post written by `xclipd`’s author](https://jameshunt.us/writings/managing-the-x11-clipboard/) for details.

Comment: @dirkc, Hi! You had any success with your app (or with finding a PopClip alternative) by any chance? Would be very grateful if you could share.. :)

Comment: @AS, unfortunately not, but mainly because of other parallel projects ;-)

Comment: @dirkc I hope one day you could find time to finish it! There's really no analog for such utility on Linux.

Answer (score 1):

Conventionally, [selecting text puts it into the *primary* selection](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/clipboards-spec/clipboards-latest.txt) (that's not clipboard).

There is [`clipnotify`](https://github.com/cdown/clipnotify) but it triggers when both primary or clipboard get owned, but it is easy to remove the clipboard part to create `primarynotify.c`:

```c
#include <X11/Xatom.h>
#include <X11/Xlib.h>
#include <X11/extensions/Xfixes.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) {
    Display *disp;
    Window root;
    XEvent evt;

    disp = XOpenDisplay(NULL);
    if (!disp)
        exit(1);

    root = DefaultRootWindow(disp);

    XFixesSelectSelectionInput(disp, root, XA_PRIMARY, XFixesSetSelectionOwnerNotifyMask);

    XNextEvent(disp, &evt);
    XCloseDisplay(disp);
}
```

Then compile it (depends on [Xfixes](https://www.x.org/releases/X11R7.6/doc/man/man3/Xfixes.3.xhtml)):

```
cc -lX11 -lXfixes -o primarynotify primarynotify.c
```

and run it in a shell loop,

```
while primarynotify; do
    echo "Primary owned: A selection has just been made."
done
```

Remember to put `primarynotify` in some `$PATH` directory or you have to give its full path.

Comment: Is there a way to expand on this example and get the absolute coordinates of the highlighted text?